# Does MongoDB has a centralized way to get node status for sharded replica sets?

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I have a mongodb cluster running 11 shards across 25 host machines.  Each shard is based on a replica set spread across 3 instances (2 data + 1 arbiter).

Is there some easy centralized way I can get node status via mongos?  I like the data output by sh.status(), but it doesn't tell me if any of the nodes are down.

I know that I can log into 11 different nodes and run rs.status() on each (if I know which ones are working), but seems like it would be good to have some centralized way of getting status for both the shards and their underlying replica sets.  Is there?

Comment: No. Either use http://cloud.mongodb.com or a monitoring solution of choice. Personally, I prefer Zabbix.

Comment: Besides that, you seem to use instances for multiple roles. Bad choice, since shutting down once instance due to maintenance work weakens the availability and - depending on the setup - makes updates difficult. TCO typically increases beyond the cost of a few cheapo VMs.